# Junit: Test Spring (auto)wiring with reflection?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, reflection, junit

Is it possible to JUnit test if wiring by Spring is succesfully?

I would like to do this by reflection. Like: get all beans with id `*Controller` and test if the fields `*services` are not null?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- build your `ApplicationContext` either via `XmlWebApplicationContext`'s constructor or via the [spring JUnit test runner](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management) and make your test implement `ApplicationContextAware`
- use the methods of `ApplicationContext` to find and verify everything you need, with the help of `ReflectionUtils` and `ReflectionTestUtils`. But have in mind that if injection fails, the whole context initialization fails.

Answer (score 4):

A better way is to annotate the setter methods with org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required, and add the required annotations post processor:

```
<!--
    This bean will cause an error if you forget to supply any properties
    annotated with @Required on the setter method; this is good for
    catching errors.
-->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

If you want to verify that methods that match a certain pattern have the @Required annotation, implement a compiler hook, an AnnotationProcessor, that causes a compiler failure if methods matching a certain pattern aren't annotated with @Required.